# How to switch between .dart files using BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I couldn't figure out a way to switch between .dart files using BottomNavigationBar. I'm new to dart and there was actually a lot of information on the internet, but I couldn't see anything referring to this in particular.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Page1m1.dart';
import 'Page1m2.dart';
import 'Page1m3.dart';

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('justworkalr'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('justworkalr'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('justworkalr'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate there. [This](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) might help you.

Generally speaking, to change screens, you want to have a "clickable" Widget (or at least something that triggeres events you can use to detect interaction of the user) and trigger the route navigation from there like:

```
// Within the `FirstRoute` widget
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
}
```

For your case [this other](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) example might help you too. You can see that an `_onItemTapped` method is triggered by the `onTab` property to change state. This would be a good location to place the navigation into.

```
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    // navigate somewhere or change content according to index

    // for example change state and set the index to current selected 
    // this will load the other widget defined above
    setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to make the "BottomNavigationBar"s items clickable?

Comment: No, this was just generally speaking. In your case, the `onTab` method of the `ButtonNavigationBar` would trigger the `_onItemTapped` function. There you can either select another widget/screen to show or completely navigate somewhere else.

Comment: child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex), can you explain me what this does lastly Alex?

Comment: This was from the example in the second link. I didn't want to copy&past over that many code but I'll change the answer so be complete.

Comment: Oh i see now.. , Thank you Alex!